# MySQL Subselect Limit

Tags: php, mysql

What im trying to do was to list all categories and their posts but only limit posts per category. And exclude a category without any posts.

I did this with two queries though, get all the categories that have posts, loop the results and get X number of posts per category ID.

How can I do this in just 1 query?

**EDIT:** this is what I accomplished so far..

```
SELECT p.post_id, c.category_id
FROM category as c
JOIN posts AS p ON p.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE
FIND_IN_SET(p.post_id, (
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.post_ids, ',', 10)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(b.post_id) AS post_ids, b.category_id
        FROM posts as b
        GROUP BY b.category_id
    ) AS a
    WHERE a.category_id = c.category_id
))
```

Comment: Use variables to simulate ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: Give us something. What is your database schema? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude all categories without any posts do an inner join between category and post. If you want to limit the number of rows returned, use the [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) command.

Answer (score -2):

how about something like this

```
SELECT  `category_name` 
FROM  `categories` 
WHERE  `posts` !=0
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: -1, `x-number of posts per category` requires a subselect and a limit in the inner select. Not something trivial like this.